# Alamofire SSL error on local dev site

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to develop a app on my local machine with the local version of my api, but I am keep getting this error when I run alamofire get request.

```
[BoringSSL] Function nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished: line 1436 Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLFatalAlert(-9802) alert
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.056793-0500 Edev[6851:453243] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x60c000178480]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.057251-0500 Edev[6851:453243] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.057432-0500 Edev[6851:453243] Task <97194E8E-7E15-42EC-B8BA-534AC4E313A2>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.057686-0500 Edev[6851:453245] Task <97194E8E-7E15-42EC-B8BA-534AC4E313A2>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
    FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60400044f570 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://edev.test/edev, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://edev.test/edev, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
    [BoringSSL] Function nw_protocol_boringssl_input_finished: line 1436 Peer disconnected during the middle of a handshake. Sending errSSLFatalAlert(-9802) alert
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.056793-0500 Edev[6851:453243] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x60c000178480]: 3:-9802 Err(-9802)
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.057251-0500 Edev[6851:453243] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.057432-0500 Edev[6851:453243] Task <97194E8E-7E15-42EC-B8BA-534AC4E313A2>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9802])
    2018-08-13 10:47:23.057686-0500 Edev[6851:453245] Task <97194E8E-7E15-42EC-B8BA-534AC4E313A2>.<1> finished with error - code: -1200
    FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60400044f570 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9802, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9802}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://edev.test/edev, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://edev.test/edev, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

This is the alamofire I am using to fetch the data

```
Alamofire.request("https://edev.test/edev").responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
            print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result

            if let json = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(json)") // serialized json response
            }

            if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
            }
        }
```

I have have put a domain exception if my plist file that should make this run successfully based on what I have found online, but it still is not working.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>edev.test</key>
        <dict/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/> 
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

does the server have an SSL certificate? if not change URL to `Alamofire.request("http://edev.test/edev").responseJSON { response in`